# Совместить похожие элементы списка в одну строку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Решал задачу с codewars, вот что должна возвращать функция:

- accum("abcd") -> "A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd"
- accum("RqaEzty") -> "R-Qq-Aaa-Eeee-Zzzzz-Tttttt-Yyyyyyy"
- accum("cwAt") -> "C-Ww-Aaa-Tttt"

Вот мой код:

```
def accum(s):
lst = []
r = -1
b = []
for i in s:
    r += 1
    lst.append(i)
    b += lst[r] * r

a = '-'.join(b)

return a.title()
```

print(accum("ZpglnRxqenU"))

Функция возвращает строку и делит каждый символ знаком "-", как мне совместить повторяющиеся элементы?

P.S не ругайте за возможный велосипед, я новичек)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с того, что ваша функция "глотает" первый символ. Во-вторых она все выводит большими буквами. И в третьих -  зачем все так сложно?

```
def accum(s):
    a=""
    for i,elt in enumerate(s):
        a = a+"-"+elt.upper()
        for _ in range(i):
            a = a+elt.lower()
    return a[1:]
print(accum("ZpglnRxqenU"))
```

Результат:

```
Z-Pp-Ggg-Llll-Nnnnn-Rrrrrr-Xxxxxxx-Qqqqqqqq-Eeeeeeeee-Nnnnnnnnnn-Uuuuuuuuuuu
```

Другие контрольные прогоны:

```
print(accum("RqaEzty"))
R-Qq-Aaa-Eeee-Zzzzz-Tttttt-Yyyyyyy


print(accum("abcd"))
A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd

print(accum("cwAt"))
C-Ww-Aaa-Tttt
```

Небольшой костыль в последней строчке функции - return a[1:] -  позволяет избежать множества лишних проверок в цикле.

Answer (score 0):

```
def accum(s):
    kol = 0
    st = ""
    for i in s:
        kol += 1
        if kol == 1:
            st += i.upper()
        else:
            st += '-' + i.upper() + i.lower() * (kol - 1)    
    return st
```

Первое условие нужно для того, чтобы проверить: в первый ли раз строка вошла в цикл.